# How can i get top 2 max values from an array of float numbers in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I need to get the 2 max value from an array of float number i.e. one highest and one second highest.Is there any simple way of getting the along with their indexes or do I need to change the array to structure for this?

Comment: sort and get first 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just sort the array and take the required value

```
var array1 = [2.1, 2.2, 2.5, 3.0, 4.2, 2]

var array2 = array1.sort(){ $0 > $1}

//One way 
let firstMax = array2[0]
let secondMax = array2[1]

//Second way
let firstMax = array2.removeFirst()
let secondMax = array2.removeFirst()
```

**EDIT**

If you want the indexes just get them like

```
let maxPos = array1.indexOf(firstMax)
let secMaxPos = array1.indexOf(secondMax)
```

If you are confused with these things just follow the normal basics as follows.

```
var max = -1.0, maxPos = -1, secMax = -1.0, secMaxPos = -1
for (index, value) in array1.enumerate() {
    if value > max {
        max = value
        maxPos = index
    } else if value > secMax {
        secMax = value
        secMaxPos = index
    }
}
print("max:\(max)->pos:\(maxPos)::secMax:\(secMax)->secMaxPos:\(secMaxPos)")
```

Comment: your code for this is good and short but it does not provide me with the indexes.

Comment: There are something wrong with your edit  

result will be : max:4.2->pos:4::secMax:2.0->secMaxPos:5

Comment: func secondLargest(arr: [Int]){
    var max1 = -1;
    var max2 = -1;
    for item in arr {
        if item > max1 {
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = item
        }else if item > max2 {
            max2 = item
        }
    }
    print(max2)
}

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enumerate()` to create an array of tuples that contain (index, value) and then sort that array by value to find the two largest values:

```
let arr: [Float] = [1.2, 3.14, 1.609, 2.718, 0.3]

// Create an array of (index, value) tuples sorted by value
// in decreasing order
let result = arr.enumerate().sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }
print(result)
```

> ```
> [(1, 3.1400001), (3, 2.71799994), (2, 1.60899997), (0, 1.20000005), (4, 0.300000012)]
> ```

```
let (topIndex, top) = result[0]
print("top = \(top), index = \(topIndex)")
```

> ```
> top = 3.14, index = 1
> ```

```
let (secondIndex, second) = result[1]
print("second = \(second), index = \(secondIndex)")
```

> ```
> second = 2.718, index = 3
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```swift
import Algorithms

[1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2].max(count: 2) // [5, 6]
```

https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/MinMax.md

Answer (score 0):

```
func secondLargest(arr: [Int]){
var max1 = -1;
var max2 = -1;
for item in arr {
    if item > max1 {
        max2 = max1;
        max1 = item
    }else if item > max2 {
        max2 = item
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try in your play gorund

var item = [2.01 ,3.95,1.85,2.65,1.6]

var sorted = item.sort({ $0 > $1 })

print (sorted)

Answer (score -1):

The basic idea is to loop through the array and pick out the largest and second largest item.

Some short code that might be hard to read:

```
let myFloatArray : [Float] = ...
let top2 = myFloatArray.enumerated().reduce(((-1, Float.nan), (-1, Float.nan)), combine: { t, v in
    // Check if value is larger than first item in tuple
    if (!(v.1 <= t.0.1)) {
        // Check if value is larger than second item in tuple
        if (!(v.1 <= t.1.1)) {
            // Return with new value as largest
            return (t.1, v)
        } else {
            // Return with new value as next largest
            return (v, t.1)
        }
    }
    // Return old result
    return t
})
```

Or with more explicit variable names:

```
var largestIndex = -1;
var largestValue = Float.nan;
var secondLargestIndex = -1;
var secondLargestValue = Float.nan;
for index in 0..<myFloatArray.count {
    let value = myFloatArray[index];
    if (!(value <= secondLargestValue)) {
        if (!(value <= largestValue)) {
            secondLargestValue = largestValue;
            secondLargestIndex = largestIndex;
            largestValue = value;
            largestIndex = index;
        } else {
            secondLargestValue = value;
            secondLargestIndex = index;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

var array2 = array1.sorted(){ $0 > $1}

print(array2)

//One way

let firstMax = array2[0]

let secondMax = array2[1]

//Answer

print(firstMax)

print(secondMax)

Answer (score -1):

```html
import UIKit

var array = [6,4,3,5,9,7,8,2,10]
var maxValue = 0, temp = 0, maxIndex = 0
for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {
    if (item > temp){
        maxIndex = index
    }
}
array.remove(at: maxIndex)
for (_, item) in array.enumerated() {
   if (item > maxValue){
       maxValue = item
    }
}

print("---------")
print(maxValue)
print("---------")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
var numberArray = [4.4,5.3,3.2,2.1,6.0,1.2,9.6,8.0,9.4]
var secontLargestValue = 0.0
var firstLargestValue = 0.0

for value in numberArray {
    if value > firstLargestValue {
        secontLargestValue = firstLargestValue
        firstLargestValue = value
    } else if (value > secontLargestValue && value != firstLargestValue) 
    {
        secontLargestValue = value
    }
}

print("First largest value - \(firstLargestValue)")
print("Second largest value - \(secontLargestValue)")
```